# What is 'this' referencing when it is inside a prototype?

Tags: javascript

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

Stolen from Crockford's Good Parts. When the code returns 'this', what does 'this' reference in this case?

I always ask myself this when I see 'this' inside a js code because I know that js is funky with the word this (i.e. 'this' actually references the global variable when it is used inside a nested function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are extending `Function.prototype`, `this` will refer to a function instance.

Example:

```
function foo() {};

foo.method(); // `this` refers to foo
```

There are like four different ways of calling functions, which determine what `this` refers to. MDN has a [good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this#Function_context) about it.

In short:

- Simple function call: Global object (`window` in browsers)
- Object method: The object (i.e. `obj.method()`, `this` references `obj`) (that's the case we have in your example)
- Using the `new` keyword: An empty object, inheriting from the functions prototype
- `call` / `apply`: Whatever you pass as first argument

Answer (score 1):

In this context, `this` is a reference to the  `Function` Instance.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the constructor Function that calls it's `method` method. So for example you can do this:

```
function Car(color){
  this.color = color || 'blue';
}

Car.method('showcolor',function(){return this.color;});
//^Car is a constructor function, so 'this' in 'method' refers to Car here

var redcar = new Car('red'), yellowcar = new Car('yellow'); 
alert(redcar.showcolor()); //=> red
alert(yellowcar.showcolor()); //=> ... you guessed it!
```