# When this is null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a simple queue for functions that take callbacks. My problem is that in the flush method, "this" is null when the action being performed is some long-running thing (in my case, indexedDB calls). I've never experienced this sort of behavior before, so please educate me on what is going on?

Here's the code:

```
var Queue = (function () {
    function Queue() {
    };

    Queue.prototype.items = [];
    Queue.prototype.results = [];
    Queue.prototype.add = function (action) {
        this.items.push(action);
    };
    Queue.prototype.complete = function () { };
    Queue.prototype.flush = function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        if (args.length > 0) { this.results.push(args); }
        if (this.items.length > 0) {
            var action = this.items.shift();
            action.call(this);
        } else { // Complete, call back multi.
            var results = this.results;
            this.clear();
            this.complete(results);
        }
    };
    Queue.prototype.clear = function () {
        this.items = [];
        this.results = [];
    };

    Queue.create = function () {
        return new Queue;
    };

    return Queue;
})();
```

Comment: Which line? What did you think `this` was, and what did it turn out to be instead? Narrow down the issue to 5-6 lines of code, by removing irrelevant bits (but not just deleting; you may need to refactor around the removals!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Inside the flush method. I expected this to be the instance of Queue, instead it was null.

Comment: I'm asking a more generic question than fixing this precise issue: when is this not the instance of the prototype?

Comment: If you have a generic question then you should present a generic testcase. Look closely at the meaning of `this` -- it doesn't care about any "prototype". It originally happened to represent the prototype only because it relates to _the owner of the current function_. Obviously, you're in a new function now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971456/accessing-global-property-using-this-keyword-inside-a-function

Comment: If Queue doesn't own its methods, how do I get a reference to the Queue instance from within one if its methods?

Comment: **Duplicate** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395280/what-is-this-referencing-when-it-is-inside-a-prototype

Comment: @Matthew: `this` does point to the instance on which the function was called, but only if you call the function directly on the instance (e.g. `myQueue.flush()`). Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess, based on what you've given us, is that you're passing a reference to the `Queue.prototype.flush` **function object** to some asynchronous function so it can be used as a callback. If that's true, `flush()` is called like this:

```js
function ayncFunction(callback) {
    // Do some stuff
    callback();
}
ayncFunction(myQueue.flush);
```

... instead of like this:

```
myQueue.flush();
```

Because the function is called separately, instead of on an object, `this` will be set `window` (unless you're using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode), in which case it's `undefined`).

You can circumvent the problem by wrapping the call to `myQueue.flush()` in a function, like this:

```
var myCallback = function() {
    myQueue.flush();
};
ayncFunction(myCallback);
```

This works because `myCallback` becomes a **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)** around `myQueue`.

Another way to solve the problem is to use **[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)** to tie the function to its context (i.e. the object on which it should be called).

Comment: Actually, `this` will refer to the owner of the "method", which is `window`.

Comment: This is the correct interpretation of what is going on. I will try the first method.

Comment: bind() works wonderfully, thank you @PPvG.  I just needed to create a new function with: var func = queue.flush.bind(queue); and pass that as the callback. Simple.